# Why are there Network Security Groups created automatically in azure and there is no bind Subnet?

Tags: azure-virtual-network

There are some pools in my batch accounts are created using this VNet and Subnet. Usually when we create VNet, we will bind an NSG in its Subnet, but the Subnet has no corresponding NSG attached.

1. So I don't understand why the irregular NSG in the picture was created and there was no Subnet.
2. Why the 'deployIfNotExists' Policy action failed.

Does anyone know about these?

Answer (score 0):

When you [create an Azure Batch pool in a virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-virtual-network), you don't have to specify NSGs at the virtual network subnet level, because Batch configures its own NSGs.

> **Batch automatically allocates additional networking resources in the
> resource group containing the VNet.**
>
> For each 100 dedicated or low-priority nodes, Batch allocates: **one
> network security group (NSG), one public IP address, and one load
> balancer**. These resources are limited by the subscription's resource
> quotas. For large pools, you might need to request a quota increase
> for one or more of these resources.

You will also could check the activity log from network security group. Event initiated by Azure Batch.

[image]